# Creating attribute accessors with optional defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, default

I have a Rails application with a recurring need for setting default attributes. Sometimes the user will supply values for the attributes which will be respected, but in other circumstances either the model or the user might desire that these attributes are overridden with default values disregarding original values.

I guessed that this problem called for a banged (`!`) and non-banged method for setting default values allowing the user and program to switch to the appropriate state. The non-banged setter will only set default values when they are not nil whilst the banged version will always overwrite the attributes with defaults. The difference is minor:

```
class BangDiBang
  attr_accessor :value

  def set_default
    self.value ||= do_some_suff_to_determine_default_value
  end

  def set_default!
    self.value = do_some_suff_to_determine_default_value
  end

  ...
end
```

The issue with this code is that if I had a bunch of variables to set, I would end up repeating the same code twice for each variable.

My question is how to partial out this code? Saving the logic in one method and having two methods `set_value` and `set_value!` calling the central logic with the different assignment operators.

I have conjured one solution: write the central logic as text, replace the assignment operation from the setter methods and evaluate (but this does not feel right). How do I not repeat myself?

Comment: What about creating a concern with it and include them everywhere you need them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're going about this isn't going to work for multiple params since you're calling `set_default` but not specifying which variable. You'll want to define behavior for each variable, ideally. There are libraries that handle this sort of thing, but you can roll your own pretty easily:

```
class Example
  def self.default_param(name, default_value)
    define_method("default_#{name}") { default_value }

    define_method(name) do 
      instance_variable_get("@#{name}") || default_value
    end

    attr_writer name
  end

  default_param :foo, 'foo default'
end

ex = Example.new
ex.foo #=> "foo default" 
ex.foo = 'bar'
ex.foo #=> "bar"
ex.default_foo #=> "foo default"
```

I've renamed `set_default` and `set_default!` to be more clear: for each variable with a default value, three methods are created (example using `foo` as the variable name):

1. `foo` — returns the value of `@foo` if it is truthy, and `default_foo` otherwise
2. `foo=` — sets the value of `@foo`
3. `default_foo` — returns the specified default

You could compartmentalize and dry up some of the code above further, creating a `default_params` (plural) method to take a hash, extracting the class macro to a concern:

```
module DefaultParams
  def default_param(name, default_value)
    define_method("default_#{name}") { default_value }

    define_method(name) do 
      instance_variable_get("@#{name}") || default_value
    end

    attr_writer name
  end

  def default_params(params)
    params.each { |default|  default_param(*default) }
  end
end

class Example
  extend DefaultParams
  default_params foo: 'default foo', bar: 'my favorite bar'
end
```

Comment: I needed a little hint that I simply did not think of at first: having a default_value method for each attribute that should have a default. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution with great inspiration from [coreyward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203130/coreyward). I did not realize at first that rather than having two methods for setting an array of default values, I needed the default values separated out into single methods. This gives a great flexibility to the design of the application. So thanks a lot for the answer.

For the rails setup I’ve added to `application_record.rb`

```
def set_attr_from_defaults
  default_attrs.each do |atr|
    eval("self.#{atr[0..atr.length-9]} ||= self.#{atr}")
  end
end

def set_attr_from_defaults!
  default_attrs.each do |atr|
    eval("self.#{atr[0..atr.length-9]} = self.#{atr}")
  end
end

def set_default_attr params
  params.each { |key, value| self.define_singleton_method(key){value} }
end

def default_attrs
  self.attributes.keys.map{|i| (i+'_default').to_sym} & self.methods
end
```

`default_attrs` yields a list of symbols off default attributes. `set_default_attr` defines singleton methods, with intended use of parsing in a hash like `attrname_default: 'default_value' ...`. The `set_attr_from_defaults` will set attributes from default values, when an attribute has a pair like `var: var_default`. The number `9` is the length of `_default` + 1.